# range keyword and 2d slices in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying my hand at Go for the first time. For the last hour or so I've been at a loss as to why this code is not working.

```
grid := make([][]string, 2)
for _, row := range grid {
    row = []string{"foo", "bar"}
}
fmt.Println(grid)
```

I expect it to print something like

```
[
  ["foo", "bar"]
  ["foo", "bar"]
]
```

but instead it refuses to compile with the message `row declared and not used`.

Clearly I'm missing something with regards to 2d slices and the `range` keyword. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`row` isn't a reference to the value in `grid`, it's a copy of the slice value. The error is because you assign a new slice to `row`, but that value is never used.

This is more likely what you want:

http://play.golang.org/p/86yHqw_JX-

```
grid := make([][]string, 2)
for i := range grid {
    grid[i] = []string{"foo", "bar"}
}
fmt.Println(grid)
```